# How to increase your rank?

Tags: dont-get-fired

In the `collections`menu you can see your `rank` currently mine is at `slave`.

The tutorial states that you can increase it to get a 3% promotion chance bonus per rank. However it doesn't say what you have to do to increase your rank.

So how can you increase your rank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase your rank from `slave` to `Lower Class` by purchasing the car.

You can further increase your rank by getting married and also by buying a house.

Comment: Why have you answered yourself?..

Comment: @matan7890: because StackExchange encourages you to do so. Read https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ :)

Comment: @matan7890 to help other people

Comment: @Konerak I believe your link is broken.

Comment: @matan7890: temporary problem with the blog, team is looking into it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303478/share-your-knowledge-qa-style-link-is-broken

Comment: @matan7890 and fixed :)